# How to adjust coordinate ranges of a paused animation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I would like to be able to change the xlim and ylim of an animated plot when the animation is either running or is in the stopped state. Changing them (using ax.set_xlim/set_ylim calls) while animation is running works fine, but if I pause the animation using event_source.stop(), then the numbers drawn along the coordinate axes remain unchanged.

Here is the test program that shows this problem. Try pressing '-' and '+' keys while the animation is running --- you will see that the blue object is scaled AND the coordinate ranges are updated. But if you first press SPACE to pause the animation and then press '-' or '+', then only the blue object is scaled, but the coordinate ranges remain as they were (and animation is resumed as a side effect of the call to ani._end_redraw(None)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from numpy import sin, cos, pi

def keypress(event):
    global anim_running
    if event.key == ' ':
        ani.event_source.stop() if anim_running else ani.event_source.start()
        anim_running = not anim_running
    elif event.key == '+':
        ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
        ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
        ani._end_redraw(None)
    elif event.key == '-':
        ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
        ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
        ani._handle_resize()
        ani._end_redraw(None)

phi = pi/2

def animate(i):
    global phi
    line.set_data([[0.0, sin(phi)], [0.0, cos(phi)]])
    phi += 0.01
    return line,

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim([-2,2])
ax.set_ylim([-2,2])
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', lw=2, color='b')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, interval=0, frames=2000)
anim_running = True
plt.show()
```

Comment: Again, this only is a problem with blitting being used. So that requirement should be part to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete canvas should be redrawn to ensure the changes to the limits being observable. I guess a good strategy would be to 1. change limits, 2. draw canvas, 3.stop animation, grab new background (via `_handle_resize`), 4. restart animation (via `_end_redraw`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from numpy import sin, cos, pi

def keypress(event):
    global anim_running
    if event.key == ' ':
        ani.event_source.stop() if anim_running else ani.event_source.start()
        anim_running = not anim_running
    elif event.key == '+':
        ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
        ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
        fig.canvas.draw()
        ani._handle_resize()
        ani._end_redraw(None)
    elif event.key == '-':
        ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
        ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
        fig.canvas.draw()
        ani._handle_resize()
        ani._end_redraw(None)

phi = pi/2

def animate(i):
    global phi
    line.set_data([[0.0, sin(phi)], [0.0, cos(phi)]])
    phi += 0.01
    return line,

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim([-2,2])
ax.set_ylim([-2,2])
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', lw=2, color='b')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit=True, interval=2, frames=2000)
anim_running = True
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it works! Again you have helped me. I hope one day I will be able to repay you for your kindness! :)